# Cordova TIMEOUT ERROR

Tags: android, cordova

i know that there are many question with same issue...

i have create phonegap app using cordova 3.2.everything was working fine. but after some time 
I am getting

> CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!

and application close with this error.

Then i have upgrad cordova framework 3.2 to cordova 3.5.
but getting same error but my application not close  this time. but my back button is not working.
 i am already use

```
 <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="30000" />
```

in config.xml file but not improvement but getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Consider, your using network plugin. If your device has wifi enabled but poor internet connection, in that case, it gives timeout error. 
P.S : I have got situation where i got this error in offline too sometimes.

Workaround :

**Sample.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./yourmain.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now map your html file in "yourmain" place. So that Sample.html should be your main html file.

Simple solution.

May be many have answered, but tis one worked for me. so i posted.

Thanks.